# Code Coverage for Case Comment Trigger

Tags: code-coverage, case, case-comment

I have a trigger where when a case field called Macro is updated, it creates a case comment accordingly.
I'm trying to get code coverage, I only get 21%, and I can't seem to get the following lines for each Macro option covered:
ParentId
Commentbody
IsPublished
casecommentlist(add)

Here's a smidge of test code (there's the same code for each Macro option)

```
static testMethod void testCaseMacros1() {
test.startTest();

Id ortId = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE Name='Detect - Fatigue Management (DSS)'].id;
RecordType rtAcct = [select Id from RecordType WHERE Name = 'Worksite' and SobjectType = 'Account' limit 1];
//create account
Account a1 = new Account(Name='Carlin Test', RecordType = rtAcct, DSS_Account__c = true);
User thisUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];        
System.runAs (thisUser) {
    
    Case cse = new Case(RecordTypeId = ortId, Site_Dealer_Name_DSS__c = a1.Id, CW_Type__c = 'Incident', Subsystem_Type__c = 'Detect Analytics - API',
    Status = 'New', Subject = 'This is my case', Description = 'This is my description', Incident_Start__c=Date.today());
    Database.insert(cse);
    
    cse.Macros__c = 'Application Support information';
    Database.update(cse);
   
  
     system.debug('cs --> ' + cse);
system.debug('cs --> ' + cse.Macros__c);
system.assertEquals('Application Support information' , cse.Macros__c);
     List<caseComment> caseCommentList = [Select Id from caseComment];
        system.assert(caseCommentList.size()>0, 'caseComment not created'); 
    
  }
  test.stopTest();

}}
```

Here's a smidge of trigger code, again, same for each Macro option:

```
  

    trigger CW_DSS_CaseTrigger on Case (after update) {
  if(CWcheckRecursive.runOnce())
    {
    
   
   List<caseComment> caseCommentList = new List<caseComment>();
    for (Case c: Trigger.new)
    {
        
        caseComment cc = new caseComment();
        if(c.Macros__c == 'Application Support information'){
                cc.parentid = c.ID;
                cc.commentbody = 'For application (DSSi and Relay Server) support and troubleshooting requests, please provide the following information.'+'\n' +
                                    'Minimum DSS Ticket Information requirements:'+'\n' +
                                    'Site Name:' +'\n' +
                                    'Site Contact: (For possible Site IT related issues)' +'\n' +
                                    'DSSi Software Version:' +'\n' +
                                    'Problem/Inquiry:' +'\n' +
                                    'Troubleshooting Steps Taken:' +'\n' +
                                    'This information is required with all DSS support requests. Failure to provide this requested information may delay your request.';
                cc.ispublished = true;
                casecommentlist.add(cc);
                System.debug('********************************************************************'+ cc.commentbody);
               
        }If(caseCommentList.Size() > 0){
            insert caseCommentList;
            System.debug('********************************************************************'+ caseCommentList);
            }
            
          
    
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain that this is causing the problem:

```
if(CWcheckRecursive.runOnce())
```

Most "recursion checks" tend to mess up unit tests, because static variables are not reset between trigger calls within the same transaction. You should dump this and go with a rising-edge-based solution:

```
 trigger CW_DSS_CaseTrigger on Case (after update) {
    List<caseComment> caseCommentList = new List<caseComment>();
    for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
        Case oldCase = Trigger.old.get(c.Id);
        caseComment cc = new caseComment();
        // If field changed, and is a certain value, add comment.
        if( oldCase.Macros__c != c.Macros__c && c.Macros__c == 'Application Support information') {
            cc.parentid = c.ID;
            cc.commentbody = 'For application (DSSi and Relay Server) support and troubleshooting requests, please provide the following information.'+'\n' +
            'Minimum DSS Ticket Information requirements:'+'\n' +
            'Site Name:' +'\n' +
            'Site Contact: (For possible Site IT related issues)' +'\n' +
            'DSSi Software Version:' +'\n' +
            'Problem/Inquiry:' +'\n' +
            'Troubleshooting Steps Taken:' +'\n' +
            'This information is required with all DSS support requests. Failure to provide this requested information may delay your request.';
            cc.ispublished = true;
            casecommentlist.add(cc);
        }
    }
    insert caseCommentList;
}
```

Note also you had the DML operation **inside** the loop. I moved it outside for you. Make sure you pay attention to your curly brackets.